# What would I use to replace the css 'property' method so that I can imitate its use in a sass file?

Tags: css, sass, properties, mixins, css-variables

Trying to recreate some css styles in a sass file and I ran across an issue which is making me think that the sass preprocessor is actually less capable then a basic css.

** **Edited** **

Within the sass file I declared the variable like this:

```
@property --gradient-angle 
  syntax: "<angle>"
  initial-value: 0deg
  inherits: false
```

and I am using it like this:

```
.card::before, 
.card::after 
  content: ""
  position: absolute
  inset: -0.5rem
  z-index: -1
  border-radius: inherit
  background: conic-gradient(var(--gradient-angle), $color-3, $color-4, $color-6, $color-4, $color-3)
  animation: rotation 20s linear infinite

.card::after 
  filter: blur(3.5rem)

  

@keyframes rotation 
  0% 
    --gradient-angle: 0deg
  100% 
    --gradient-angle: 360deg
```

The code runs but none of the colors in `background: conic-gradient(var(--gradient-angle), $color-3, $color-4, $color-6, $color-4, $color-3)` are being read because the initial call for it's gradient angle is either null or undefined. I think this may be a syntax error, not sure.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: the @property does work on Sass if you correctly write it without any syntax error

Comment: I expect the `$gradient-angle` variable to animate the degree of the background's gradient by giving that variable `@keyframes` and adding the variable itself as the degree measure for the conic-gradient of the background.

Comment: What is the correct way to write the @property method in sass?